# Cordova(PhoneGap) and android setResult

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova

My problem is:
A has a intent with action.PICK. B can use intent filter to catch A's intent. But how can I use **Cordova** to **setResult** and return to A?

In android, we can use **intent filter** to catch some requests(intents) from other app.
A caller(parent) can call **startActivityForResult** to start another activity and get a result from it in **onActivityResult**.
 The callee(child) activity can use **setResult** and **finish** to return a result to parent.
I can use intent filter to catch an intent in Cordova. But the problem is, I don't know how to return an image URI to it parent in javascript.
 Is there any advice? Thanks.

Comment: you need to developer plugin for that, i hope you have an idea for that

Comment: yes, i have finished this work. thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1245516 Have you finally managed to do it, can you share an example as an answer of the plugin you used? Best